# Checking an Item in list and delete then item if date matches with current date Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database like this with many events

[image]

I want to match the date of the event with the current date and sent a notification to user about the event. I am clear with the notification part. Can anyone help me how to access the list.get(position).getDate() of any event without clicking on the item in recycler view.

I tried this

```
for(int position =0;position<list.size();position++){
Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
String formattedDate = df.format(c);
if (list.get(position).getDate().compareTo(formattedDate) == 0) {
    final String itemId2 = list.get(position).getItemId();
    final String strDate = list.get(position).getDate();
    final String strPlace = list.get(position).getDate();
    final String strDesc = list.get(position).getDate();
    final String strName = list.get(position).getName();
    EventDetails eventDetails = new EventDetails(itemId2, strName, strPlace, strDesc, strDate, "0", "0");
    ref3.child(itemId2).setValue(eventDetails).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isComplete()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Event completed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    ref.child(itemId2).removeValue();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

But it wont work.
I want this code to work automatically on the event date and not on single click or double click of recyclerView. Can anyone please help!!?  Note that the data is in firebase.

List is private ArrayList list; which contains the data of eventDetails.java and the event details is

```
public class EventDetails {
private String itemId, name, place, desc, date, alarmHour, alarmMin;

public EventDetails() {
}

public EventDetails(String itemId, String name, String place, String desc, String date, String alarmHour, String alarmMin) {
    this.itemId = itemId;
    this.name = name;
    this.place = place;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.date = date;
    this.alarmHour = alarmHour;
    this.alarmMin = alarmMin;
}

public String getItemId() {
    return itemId;
}

public void setItemId(String itemId) {
    this.itemId = itemId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPlace() {
    return place;
}

public void setPlace(String place) {
    this.place = place;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getAlarmHour() {
    return alarmHour;
}

public void setAlarmHour(String alarmHour) {
    this.alarmHour = alarmHour;
}

public String getAlarmMin() {
    return alarmMin;
}

public void setAlarmMin(String alarmMin) {
    this.alarmMin = alarmMin;
}
```

}
and this is how I added values to the list and showed in recyclerView

```
if (ref != null) {
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    list = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        list.add(ds.getValue(EventDetails.class));
                    }
                    EventAdapter eventAdapter = new EventAdapter(list, getActivity());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(eventAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

The app doesnot crash but it doesnot carries out the desired task.

Ok so her is how I initialized ref

```
private DatabaseReference ref;
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events/"+ + Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid())
```

Comment: @Ryan Ok I added the details in question. Have a look again!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ok I edited the question. Have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attach your listener to `/Events`. Under that you have two nested levels:

1. `"UjgmW3..."`, which seems to be a user ID or something like that.
2. and then under there you have `"-MBs..."` keys, for each event.

The `DataSnapshot` that gets passed to your `onDataChange` contains the data for all events. So to get to the level of the individual events (#2 above) you will need to loop over each "user ID" snapshot first, and then within that over the events.

Something like:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot eventSnapshot: userSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    list.add(eventSnapshot.getValue(EventDetails.class));
                }
            }
            EventAdapter eventAdapter = new EventAdapter(list, getActivity());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(eventAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

I find that for cases like this it really helps to give your variables semantically meaningful names, like the `userSnapshot` and `eventSnapshot` above. Having names like that, makes it much easier to spot when you're doing something illogical like in this case: trying to read event data from a user snapshot.

Comment: Yes thank you for that sir, but that is not my problem. I am able to access the items successfully and display them in recyclerView.

Comment: My problem is I have to access the items if the recylcerView without having to click or longPress. In order to automatically deleted to carry other operations is the date of event is equal to today's date.

Comment: Sir I respect your answer but please read my question ones more, the thing which you told me is not my question so why should I mark it as completed. I would definitely upvote you for that!